# Query is slow even when joining condition columns have indexes on them in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a query as follows :

```
select distinct
    b.INSTANCE_ID, b.itemnumber, 
    isnull((a.ITEM_REV + ' ' + a.ITEM_CN), 'Introductory') itemrev, 
    b.bom_itemnumber, b.bom_rev  
into 
    parts_bom_stg2
from 
    PARTS_BOMD a
inner join 
    parts_bom_stg b on a.ITEM_NUMBER = b.itemnumber
                    and b.itemrev = a.ITEM_REV;
```

Its estimated execution plan is:

[image]

Indexes are on item_number and item_rev columns of both tables.

I can not ditch the distinct in the query. I guess its lagging because of this distinct. Does anyone know how I can optimize it. Both tables have almost 5 million rows.

Table structure of table `Parts_BOMD`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PARTS_BOMD]
(
    [BOM_ID] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [ITEM_REV] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [ITEM_CN] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [ITEM_NUMBER] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [ITEMNUMBER] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [FINDNUM] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [QTY] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [ITEMDESCRIPTION] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [ITEMREV] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [itemSize] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [REFDES] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [BOMText02] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [itemList21] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [SUMMARYCOMPLIANCE] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [BOMMULTITEXT30] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [BOMNotes] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [itemList10] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [BOMList01] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [BOMList03] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [BOMList02] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [itemText22] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [itemText23] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [itemLifecyclePhase] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [ITEMP2MULTILIST05] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [itemText15] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [RNUM] [varchar](4000) NULL
)
```

Structure of `Parts_bom_stg`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[parts_bom_stg]
(
    [INSTANCE_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [itemnumber] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [itemrev] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [bom_itemnumber] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [bom_rev] [varchar](500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Show us your **table structure!**

Comment: Why is everything `[varchar](4000)`? What indexes exist on the tables?

Comment: Because data in these columns is huge.

Comment: I find it unlikely a column called `QTY` should be `varchar` at all.

Comment: Indexes on are only item_number and item_rev columns. And yes you are right. some of these columns should have a lesser length, but its  structure is predefined and I am unauthorized to change their lengths.

Comment: Is it also slow when you leave out the INTO part ? And who designed the Parts_BOMD table ? I just want to make sure I never ever hire that guy

Comment: LOL sure. I am using into statement because I want to save the result of the query into a table. And I guess it will be faster, if I leave into part.

Comment: What are the **primary keys** on these two tables?

Answer (score 1):

if you can't change table structure or data type then atleast
explain why you can't ditch distinct.
what is your putput with or without distinct,then it will be clear.
Why you will select all rows from both the table.where you will show ?

Why don't you use paging ?

Also ITEM_NUMBER and itemrev are nullable in both table,so you can put extra condtion in where clause.

"where ITEM_NUMBER is not null and itemrev  is not null"

If you can'd  do this and that then you can re-write your query and give a try.

```
--create table  parts_bom_stg2 ()
insert into parts_bom_stg2
select 
    b.INSTANCE_ID, b.itemnumber, 
    isnull((a.ITEM_REV + ' ' + a.ITEM_CN), 'Introductory') itemrev, 
    b.bom_itemnumber, b.bom_rev  
from 
    PARTS_BOMD a
inner join 
    parts_bom_stg b on a.ITEM_NUMBER = b.itemnumber
 and b.itemrev = a.ITEM_REV
where not exists(select INSTANCE_ID from parts_bom_stg2 c 
where c.INSTANCE_ID=b.INSTANCE_ID and b.itemnumber=c.itemnumber [write the where condition properly here])
```

Comment: Without distinct I get duplicate records. And though those columns are nullable but they always have data in them. I thought of creating parts_bom_stg2 with duplicate records and then deleting the duplicates. Its creation is till under way, therefore I can not tell that the query which will be deleting duplicate records will have the same execution time or not.

Comment: Why can't you use paging ?

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: Your solution returned duplicates :) And I have got authorization for changing datatypes and length of the columns.

Comment: Congratulation,you got promoted ! Before changing data type and length you have to take back up and do thorough analysis of data.

Comment: LOL, I was amazed at the structure myself. And yes taking backup.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what I did. Its a bad way around but it did solve my problem:

```
declare @sql3 varchar(1000)
declare @sql4 varchar(1000)
declare @sql5 varchar(1000)
begin

DECLARE drop_constraint CURSOR FOR  
select distinct itemnumber, itemrev from parts_bom_stg
--print @sql3

OPEN drop_constraint  
FETCH NEXT FROM drop_constraint INTO @sql3,@sql5

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0          
 BEGIN      

 insert into parts_bom_stg2
select DISTINCT b.INSTANCE_ID,b.itemnumber, isnull((a.ITEM_REV + ' '+ a.ITEM_CN),'Introductory') itemrev, b.bom_itemnumber, b.bom_rev  

from PARTS_BOMD a
inner join parts_bom_stg b
on a.ITEM_NUMBER = b.itemnumber
and b.itemrev = a.ITEM_REV
where b.itemnumber = @sql3
and b.itemrev = @sql5

Print @sql3 + '     ' + @sql5
FETCH NEXT FROM drop_constraint INTO @sql3,@sql5

       -- open cursor to recreate references  
        --cursor in which references are stored     
      end  
     CLOSE drop_constraint          
 DEALLOCATE drop_constraint 
end
GO
```

This took almost an hour. But it was way lesser than before. The query took 2.5 hours and it still did not work.

Thank you everyone for your support. Really appreciated! :)